# How to insert core template into product view page before price?

Tags: template, layout

I am trying to insert my core template file in product view page before price using layout xml.

I've tried this.

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="myblock" as="myblock" template="mymodule/mytemplate.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

But it displays at the bottom of the content just before footer.

And then I try to add `before="product.info.simple"`

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="myblock" as="myblock" template="mymodule/mytemplate.phtml" before="product.info.simple"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

But it displays above the content just after breadcrumb.

So, anybody know how to make it displays just before the price?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you can add a block only to another block which has `core/text_list` type. So you need to find a closest block of such type to a place where you want to position your block.

If you want to make it for simple products only (which follows out of your question) you can do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
        <reference name="product.info.simple.extra">
            <block type="core/template" name="test" template="test.phtml" before="-"/>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
</layout>
```

for all types of products this is the closest you can get:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="alert.urls">
            <block type="core/template" name="test" template="test.phtml" after="-"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Comment: It should be noted that `core/text_list`-like behavior is seen in in template blocks when `getChildHtml('')` is called with empty string as first param. If the third param is passed as true it will even render children blocks by sort, just like `core/text_list` behavior.

Answer (score 6):

The alternative is to change the catalog/product/view template and add a

```
$this->getChildHtml('my_cool_block_name');
```

and add it to the `local.xml`

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="core/template" name="my_cool_block_name" template="test.phtml" after="-"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('mymodule/mytemplate.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

you are anywhere using this code.